# Null values are getting displayed in SQL server but when the same query is run through python I am getting blank instead of null

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, isnull

I have to select Maximum of a particular value or else null the query is something like MAX(X) as X when I am executing this in SQL server I am getting null values but when the same query is executed with python I am getting blank instead of null.

The null values on SQL are with Pink background hence want to replace these null values with String Null so that when the query is auto executed through Python I will get null values instead of blank

Comment: Could you please add some minimal and reproducible code example to begin with ? It will greatly increase the help you will receive

Comment: If you are using `pyodbc`then instead of `null` it returns `None` , we need to see the code first to help you better